# $rootScope.$broadcast from controller and $scope.$on in directive is not working 1.2x version

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller, angularjs-rootscope

I'm trying to call $rootScope.broadcast from my controller and want to listen it in the directive

```
Controller:

function startfunction(){
   $rootScope.$broadcast('sharingFn');
}
startfunction();

 Directive:

 $scope.$on('sharingFn',function(){
 console.log('function called");
}
```

but the directive is never called here, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a live example of your code? It's difficult to tell where the problem is from the above example.

One potential reason I can think of is the directive doesn't start listening for the event until after the 'sharingFn' event has been broadcast.